# What Constitutes a Masjid?

Tags: salat, fiqh, masjid

At my college, we have an interfaith chapel building that houses spaces for all religions. In the lower level, a storage area had been converted in the 80s to become a prayer room for only Muslims to use for salat.

- Does this mean that the prayer room is classified as a masjid?
- Does doing salat in it carry the same reward as at any other masjid?
- Is the tahiyyat al masjid sunnah prayer something that should be done there?

Comment: A masjid in Arabic from a linguistic perspective is the place of prostration so the place you prostrate on. Therefore the hadith says (https://sunnah.com/muslim/5/5):" ... the whole earth has been made a mosque for us...." What indeed is interesting to discuss is the fiqh opinions on whether or not one should perform the salutation of mosque prayer!

Answer (score 1):

> “**The (whole) earth has been made a mosque (or a place of prayer)**
>   and a means of purification for me, so wherever a man of my ummah may
>   be when the time for prayer comes, let him pray.” 
>   (Sahih Bukhari, 335)

Answer (score 0):

I am not a scholar, but from my experience, any place that many people use solely for islamic things(i.e. prayer, reading Quran, jump,etc.) will count as a masjid. so you should get the same rewards. as for the last question, there are many different opinions about whether you have to pray tahiyyat al masjid upon entering. in my experience, if I have time to pray it(ex: I'm on break or my next class is close enough that I can get there even if I pray it) then I would. you should do what you feel is right and also do some of your own research.